# Julia Lang: How to assign a concentrated load to a specific point in the boundary?

Tags: arrays, vector, julia, linear-algebra

I am a beginner in Julia and I want to assign a concentrated load pointed downwards into the middle point of the boundary of my model. Unfortunately, this code gives me some results just when the application is made in a part of the boundary (line (1D)), not at a point as I need it.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

````
using Gridap 
using GridapGmsh
import gmsh

Γ1 = BoundaryTriangulation(model, tags="upper middle point")
dΓ1 = Measure(Γ1,degree)
t1(y) = VectorValue(0.0,-100.0)
l(v) = ∫( t1 ⊙ v)*dΓ1 
op = AffineFEOperator(a,l,U,V)
uh = solve(op)    
sigma_num = evaluate(σ∘ε(uh), Point(3.0, -5.0))
show(sigma_num) ```
````

Comment: I think it's really important to list the libraries you are using here...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a load on a point, you can define a physical group in gmsh and then use Gridap to access it. In case you do not know how to work with gmsh and thus set up physical groups, please first have a look at the tutorials provided by gmsh.

If you have a gmsh model with physical groups, which are tags in Gridap, then you might want to have a look at this: [Finite Element Analysis with Gridap.jl; how to define external forces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74629951/finite-element-analysis-with-gridap-jl-how-to-define-external-forces/75033280#75033280)

It shows how forces on chosen tags, i.e., Neumann boundary condition, or on the entire domain (volume forces, Dirichlet boundary condition) can be applied.